# Curve fitting, Polynomial

Tags: fitting, interpolation

I have a data set in such a manner

```
{x,y}= {
     {10^-6,10^-15},
     {10^-5,10^-14},
     {10^-4,10^-14},
     {10^-3,10^-13},
     {10^-2,10^-11},
     {10^-1,10^-9},
     {1,10^-8}
    }
```

I want to fit a polynomial for these data sets.

Comment: see [Interpolation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html) and [Fit](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fit.html)

Comment: I've voted to close because fitting polynomials is readily available in the documentation, there is essentially no effort, and a polynomial is not appropriate for the artificial data (although a log transformation for both variables would make a polynomial more appropriate).

Answer (score 3):

```
xy = {{10^-6, 10^-15}, {10^-5, 10^-14}, {10^-4, 10^-14}, {10^-3, 
    10^-13}, {10^-2, 10^-11}, {10^-1, 10^-9}, {1, 10^-8}};
```

#### [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html)

```
ClearAll[intf]
intf = Interpolation[xy, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
Plot[intf[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

#### [`Fit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fit.html)

```
ClearAll[fitf]
fitf[x_] := Evaluate@Fit[xy, {1, x, x^2, x^3}, {x}]
Plot[fitf[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
xy = {{10^-6, 10^-15}, {10^-5, 10^-14}, {10^-4, 10^-14},
   {10^-3, 10^-13}, {10^-2, 10^-11}, {10^-1, 10^-9}, {1, 10^-8}};

{x, y} = Transpose[xy];

X = Transpose[{x^3, x^2, x^1, x^0}];

{a, b, c, d} = Inverse[Transpose[X].X].Transpose[X].y;

{from, to} = x[[{1, -1}]];

Show[ListPlot[xy, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}],
 Plot[a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d, {x, from, to}],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]